# GLSLES Losing 5-6ms using uniform float instead of e.g. 0.5

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, glsles

I have this fragment shader. On some "sprites" i want a different "saturation" of the texture. At the moment i only set it once but later i would set it each draw depending on the sprite beeing drawn. As noted in the code if i just write * 0.5 i don`t see a performance decrease but if i use * u_test the speed decreases about 5-7ms. Could that be possible? Could you think of a other solution? Am i totally in the wrong track?

```
varying vec4        v_fragmentColor; 
varying vec2        v_texCoord;
varying vec4        v_secondFragmentColor;

uniform sampler2D   CC_Texture0;

uniform vec3        u_topColor;
uniform vec3        u_centerColor;
uniform vec3        u_bottomColor;
uniform float       u_intensity;
uniform lowp float  u_test;

void main()
{
    //vec4 base = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord) * v_fragmentColor * u_test;    // 1. 5-7 ms slower that 2.
    vec4 base = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord) * v_fragmentColor * 0.5;         // 2. fast

    vec3 blend = v_secondFragmentColor.rgb;

    vec3 overlay = vec3( 2.0 * base.rgb * blend + base.rgb * base.rgb - 2.0 * base.rgb * base.rgb * blend);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(overlay, base.a);
}
```

Comment: How do you measure the 5-7 ms?

Comment: And relative to what? 5-7 minutes?

Comment: I run the Scene with around 25 Sprites on the device (iPad Retina), swaping lines 1. and 2.

Comment: Can't you just move `u_test` into the vertex shader and premultiply `v_fragmentColor`?

Comment: Are you including the time taken to set the uniform by any chance?